# Cadastro no foreach php

Tags: php, array, foreach, sql-insert

tudo bem? Estou tentando cadastrar vários registros no bd conforme o número de parcelas solicitado, porém não estou conseguindo. Meu código:

php:

```
 $Conn = parent::getConn();
    try {
        foreach ($this->Data as $pr):
            $Query = $Conn->prepare("INSERT INTO c022vdpr (dta_pedido, nro_pedido, cod_cliente, vlr_parcela, vct_parcela, nro_parcela, quitacao) VALUES (:dtaped, :nroped, :codcli, :vlrpar, :vctpar, :nropar, :quit)");
            $Query->execute(array(':dtaped' => $pr['dta_pedido'], ':codcli' => $pr['cod_cliente'], ':nroped' => $pr['nro_pedido'], ':vlrpar' => $pr['vlr_parcela'], ':vctpar' => $pr['vct_parcela'], ':nropar' => $pr['nro_parcela'], ':quit' => $pr['quitacao']
            ));
            $this->Result = true;
            $this->Error = ["<b>Atualizado!</b>", ACCEPT];
        endforeach;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->Result = false;
        $this->Error = [$e->getMessage(), ERROR];
    }
```

error = `Erro na Linha : # 168 # :: Illegal string offset`

var_dump:

```
object(AdminProd)[2]
private 'Data' => 
array (size=7)
  'dta_pedido' => string '2017-07-03' (length=10)
  'nro_pedido' => int 477037
  'cod_cliente' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
  'vlr_parcela' => float 132.5
  'vct_parcela' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '2017-08-31' (length=10)
      1 => string '2017-09-30' (length=10)
      2 => string '2017-10-31' (length=10)
  'nro_parcela' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
  'quitacao' => string 'N' (length=1)
   private 'CatId' => null
   private 'Error' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2' for column 'dta_pedido' at row 1' (length=105)
  1 => string 'error' (length=5)
  private 'Result' => boolean false
```

Comment: tem um erro ali, 
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2' for column 'dta_pedido' at row 1' (length=105)

Comment: então o formato da data esta correto pois já consegui cadastra assim em outras tabelas :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade `$this->Data` parece ser um [array associativo](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/web/php/array.php#array-associativo). Embora o PHP não faça a distinção entre array associativo e array indexado, seu código faz. Tente remover o `foreach` do código, e deve ter o resultado esperado:

```
try {
    $Query = $Conn->prepare("INSERT INTO c022vdpr (dta_pedido, nro_pedido, cod_cliente, vlr_parcela, vct_parcela, nro_parcela, quitacao) VALUES (:dtaped, :nroped, :codcli, :vlrpar, :vctpar, :nropar, :quit)");
    $Query->execute(array(':dtaped' => $this->Data['dta_pedido'], ':codcli' => $this->Data['cod_cliente'], ':nroped' => $this->Data['nro_pedido'], ':vlrpar' => $this->Data['vlr_parcela'], ':vctpar' => $this->Data['vct_parcela'], ':nropar' => $this->Data['nro_parcela'], ':quit' => $this->Data['quitacao']
    ));
    $this->Result = true;
    $this->Error = ["<b>Atualizado!</b>", ACCEPT];
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $this->Result = false;
    $this->Error = [$e->getMessage(), ERROR];
}
```

**UPDATE**

Como mencionou nos comentários, utilizou o `foreach` para gravar na base os dados do clientes + dados de cada parcela, criando linhas distintas na base para cada parcela. Consegue utilizar a propriedade `nro_parcela` no `foreach` para gravar os dados da forma que pretende:

```
try {
    foreach ($this->Data['nro_parcela'] as $k => $v):
        $Query = $Conn->prepare("INSERT INTO c022vdpr (dta_pedido, nro_pedido, cod_cliente, vlr_parcela, vct_parcela, nro_parcela, quitacao) VALUES (:dtaped, :nroped, :codcli, :vlrpar, :vctpar, :nropar, :quit)");
        $Query->execute(array(':dtaped' => $this->Data['dta_pedido'], ':codcli' => $this->Data['cod_cliente'][$k], ':nroped' => $this->Data['nro_pedido'], ':vlrpar' => $this->Data['vlr_parcela'], ':vctpar' => $this->Data['vct_parcela'][$k], ':nropar' => $v, ':quit' => $this->Data['quitacao']
        ));
        $this->Result = true;
        $this->Error = ["<b>Atualizado!</b>", ACCEPT];
    endforeach;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $this->Result = false;
    $this->Error = [$e->getMessage(), ERROR];
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O erro de antes foi resolvido, porem como acho que voce reparou que dentro do meu array no debug eu possuo mais 3 array bidimensionais que seria o numero das parcelas e cada data de vencimento em relação a quantidade de parcelas, agora me aparece isso 'Erro na Linha : # 169 # :: Array to string conversion' essa linha é a do execute!

Comment: eu estava usando foreach justamente pra cadastra todos os registros tipo 5 parcelas, então 5 registros!

Comment: Entendi. Um dos campos que define a quantidade de parcelas é o `nro_parcela`, correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo 'nro_parcela' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)

Comment: nesse caso é 3 parcela, mas, pode ser 5 6 7 até 12.

Comment: Muito obrigado!